# Missing argument 1 for give_profile_name() error after changing host

Tags: php, wordpress, web, wordpress-theming

I changed host recently. And I am seeing an error after this. I was using a piece of code at [Displaying Logged-In User Name in Wordpress Menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761566/displaying-logged-in-user-name-in-wordpress-menu)
to show the user name instead of 'profile page'. It was running fine on the previous host. After I copied everything and data, I am seeing this error on the menu bar. Users see this when they log in. Please suggest the remedy.

[image]

Following is the code that I am usign. It is exactly the same as given on the link of stackoverflow that I posted. I have created a page #profile_name# just as mentioned in the link.

```
function give_profile_name($atts){
$user=wp_get_current_user();
$name=$user->user_firstname .' '. $user->user_lastname ; 
return $name;
}

add_shortcode('profile_name', 'give_profile_name');

add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_dynamic_menu_items' );
function my_dynamic_menu_items( $menu_items ) {
foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
    if ( '#profile_name#' == $menu_item->title ) {
        global $shortcode_tags;
        if ( isset( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] ) ) {
            // Or do_shortcode(), if you must.
            $menu_item->title = call_user_func( $shortcode_tags['profile_name'] );
        }    
    }
}

return $menu_items;
}
```

Comment: Well but for the time being, can there be a solution !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you still an answer to this but I figured I would reply anyway since I ran into this same error with the same code snippet while trying to add a user's first name to a navigation menu. I noticed that it was still working despite the error, so after playing around, I just deleted the `$atts` from the function. So the first piece of the code would be:

```
function give_profile_name(){
$user=wp_get_current_user();
$name=$user->user_firstname .' '. $user->user_lastname ; 
return $name;
}
```